# Particle bouncing in a Spaceship travelling at 75% the speed of light

Tags: special-relativity

I've been studying Special Relativity and all the exercises I seem to find only deal with very simple motions...and so I wonder, what do we do about more complicated motions?

For example, let's say we have two inertial reference frames $S$ and $S^{'}$. $S^{'}$ is the reference frame of spaceship travelling at a speed of 0.75 c from frame $S$, the frame of Earth. The ship travels in a 3D straight line as shown below:
[image]

Now, we have an object $\frak{P}$ bouncing inside the spaceship. Usually this object $\frak{P}$ follows a simple path: a straight line, an oblique etc., but what if I wanted this object to follow a more interesting trajectory, for example $\langle x^{'}({{t^{'}}})=1+{t'}^{3},y^{'}({t^{'}})={t^{'}}^{2},z^{'}({t^{'}})=1\rangle$, where ${t^{'}}$ is the time in $S^{'}$.

From the POV of an observer situated in the origin $O^{'}$ of $S^{'}$ the path traced by the object is this:
[image: taken from: https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/calculus_online/section13.02.html]

**How would this motion be perceived from the POV of a second observer standing at the origin $O$ of the reference frame $S$ ?**

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have position with units of ("dimensionless plus seconds cubed", "seconds squared", "unitless"). You need coefficients, like:

Let $\langle x^{'}({{t^{'}}})=A+{Bt'}^{3},y^{'}({t^{'}})={Ct^{'}}^{2},z^{'}({t^{'}})=A\rangle$

for some constants $A, B, C$

In any case,

$\Delta x = \gamma^{-1}_x \Delta x' + $, $\Delta y = \gamma^{-1}_y \Delta y'$, $\Delta z = \gamma^{-1}_z \Delta z'$, $\Delta t = \gamma \Delta t'$

where $\gamma_x = \gamma(\vec v\cdot \hat x), \gamma_y = \gamma(\vec v\cdot \hat y), \gamma_z = \gamma(\vec v\cdot \hat z)$

$\gamma$, $\gamma_x$, and so on, multiply like any other variable, so e.g. $\Delta x' = B((t'{_0}+\Delta t')^3-t'{_0}^3) \to \Delta x = \gamma^{-1}_x B((t'{_0}+\gamma\Delta t)^3-t'{_0}^3)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't seem to understand why you wrote $\gamma_{x}$ as $\gamma(\vec v \cdot \hat x)$. Whilst I understand that we must have different $\gamma$ for x,y and z, I don't quite see how you arrived at that form. Could you please explain that bit ?

Comment: The dot product of velocity and the x direction unit vector is the amount of velocity that is in the x direction, $v cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between velocity and the x axis. Likewise for y and z. It's common to assign the x direction to be identical to the direction of the velocity to make the calculation easy. If you do that, $\gamma_y = \gamma_z = 1$ and $\gamma_x = \gamma$. But you didn't specify, so I did not assume that your trajectory was written with that in mind.

Comment: Aha, I understand it now.  I would also want to now how I should write $t^{'}$.Usually, when the direction of velocity is the same as the x direction, we write $t^{'}=\gamma(t-\frac{vx}{c^{2}})$. In the case I described the direction of velocity and the x direction no loner coincide so I was thinking of writing $t^{'}=\gamma(t-\frac{\vec v \cdot \vec r}{c^{2}})$, where $\vec r$ is the position vector with origin in $O$ and $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^{2}}{c^2}}}$. Would this be the correct way ?